# Show that the inverse function to $f(x)=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{dt}{t}$ is differentiable

Tags: integration, derivatives, inverse

Show that the inverse function to $$f(x)=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{dt}{t}$$ is differentiable.

I know that the integral is $\ln(x)$, but I don't know how to show that it is differentiable in a good way

Thanks for help

Comment: The title isn't supposed to replace the first line of your question and the superior limit is supposed to be $x$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm pretty new here.

Comment: $f$ is certainly differentiable, and its derivative (what is it?) is non-zero. Now, do you have any theorem that applies?

Comment: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: Can you express the derivative of $g^{-1}$, $g$ a general function, in terms of the derivative of $g$?

Comment: @Chappers I'm not sure. I don't really get this problem so well..

Comment: The inverse function rule says: if $g'(g^{-1}(x)) \neq 0$, $(g^{-1})'(x) = \frac{1}{g'(g^{-1}(x))}$.